# How exactly should an override of NSView's -layout method work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, layout, autolayout

I have a hierarchy of custom NSViews which I'm laying out in a style not supported by autolayout constraints.  Right now, I'm just watching for resize events, and calling `-setFrame` on all my subviews (and their subviews...), but that's not scaling very well, in terms of source code complexity.  (When I add one new subview at the bottom of the hierarchy, I have to add its layout logic way up in the top view -- that doesn't seem ideal.)

The proper way to solve this, as I understand it, is to override NSView's [-layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/layout) method (and then call `-setNeedsLayout` when I want to force a layout, at some level of the tree).

Unfortunately, the documentation for that is a bit terse, and (despite the "CocoaSlides" link there) there's no sample code from Apple that overrides this method.  I tried searching on Github, but it turns out that "layout" is a rather common word in Objective-C code, and I have yet to find one that's the one I want.

For example, let's say I have an AAView (NSView), which has some BBView's inside it which display some word-wrapped text, and it wants to display them with at 100% of its own width (vaguely like an NSStackView, I think, though that's another totally undocumented feature of Cocoa).

Because the BBViews have a height which is dependent on their width (due to their word wrapping), they can't have an `-intrinsicContentSize` (correct?).  AAView's -layout method wants to place the BBViews, i.e., to set their frameSize and frameOrigin.  In order to know BBView's size, though, it needs to ask BBView -- but BBView can't set its *own* size in its `-layout` method (only for its subviews, if it has any).  So any implementation of `-layout` in these classes also needs some out-of-band methods (like, say, a `-requestedHeightForWidth:(CGFloat)width` on BBView), at which point I'm not sure that's any better than my own ad-hoc `-setFrame` calls (i.e., what CocoaSlides actually does).

Can somebody point me at some sample code which implements `-layout` for custom NSViews?  I'm just not seeing how this is supposed to work.  Am I totally barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do what you want with autolayout using -intrinsicContentSize on BBView, assuming I understand the problem.

If your BBView always wants to always be the exact width of your AAView (or something close to that), you can just set standard horizontal constraints to enforce this. That solves the width.

To do the height, override -setFrameSize: on BBView, and if the width has changed from the old width, call -invalidateIntrinsicContentSize.

In your -intrinsicContentSize on BBView, you look at your current width and calculate the height based on how your strings lay out inside it. Return {self.frame.width, calculatedHeight} and you’re home-free. (There are obvious optimizations to this if -intrinsicContentSize is called a lot and your layout is expensive.)

EDIT: Actually, you should return (NSSize){NSViewNoInstrinsicMetric, calculatedHeight}, not the current width. Sorry.

Comment: Well, I have many problems!  I'm hoping to get a general understanding of how `-layout` can be overridden, but I'm sure you're right that I can use autolayout more than I am, such as in this (simplified) case.

Comment: One point that confused me: the Apple docs say "This intrinsic size must be independent of the content frame", but it sounds like you're saying to go ahead and depend on the content frame, and just invalidate as needed.

Comment: Right, they’re not quite correct in saying that—they mean it must be independent of the content frame OR you have to invalidate the intrinsic size yourself. I’ve done this in my code, it worked great.

Comment: I honestly haven’t been able to use -layout for anything yet. It seems kind of impractical, but maybe I don’t understand it fully.

Comment: I've been playing with this, and with a single AA and single BB, it's mostly working.  One minor oddity I found is that my `-intrinsicContentSize` needs to subtract its own `alignmentRectInsets` from the width passed to it, else it just keeps growing.  Also, for some reason I (the user) can resize the AA view to be bigger, but never smaller -- still trying to figure that one out.  Seems to have something to do with the NSScrollView/NSClipView it's in.

Comment: Ah!  Returning .width=NSViewNoIntrinsicMetric solves my resizing issue -- great!  Now the basic case works, and I just have to plumb this through the rest of my views.

Answer (score 0):

Do not look to methods involving frame for your answer. Instead - and Apple is quite clear about this - you should be using Autolayout when writing a new application. Everything is different in Autolayout-land, and intrinsicContentSize is one of the methods meant to work *with* autolayout, but manipulating frames and manually updating window sizes and positions is a dead end.